# Rising error in Robolectric test when you have try-catch in your application code

Tags: android, testing, try-catch, robolectric

In my android application I have written `try-catch` in every event method. So when an exception occurs, the catch gets the exception and a method shows a message box containing the exception details and I can handle and find my application's bugs.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
try {

} 
catch (Exception e) {
        MessageBox.showException(this, e);
    }

}
```

Now in Robolectric which there is no device to show the ui results, I cannot find out if an exception occurred. Now I want to do something when my code went to catch part or when `MessageBox.showException` is called, the test fails.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of solving this is for you to inject the component that handles the errors into the classes that use it and after that, load a customized one for your tests.

There are several ways to achieve this and probably some better than what I will suggest, but I will try and present the option that requires minimum changes to what I think is your current architecture.

1 - Whatever you use for showing exceptions, instantiate this in your Application class and keep it there. Or at least provide it from your application class, so now whenever you need to use `MessageBox`, instead of a static method, you fetch it from the `Application` first. For example:

```
((MyApplication)getApplication()).getMessageBox().showException(this,e)
```

2 - Create a `TestMessageBox` and a `TestApplication` (that extends your normal Application class). In your `TestApplication`, override `getMessageBox()` to return the `TestMessageBox` instead of the normal `MessageBox`. In your `TestMessageBox` do whatever you want to be able to observe the errors in your tests.

3 - In your tests, use the TestApplication. When you run tests, Robolectric will load this instead of the normal application so your tests will now use your `TestMessageBox` and you can capture the info you need.

```
@Config(application = TestApplication.class)
```